# Can't seem to understand this ajax call, need some pointers

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

All am doing is taking value from input when button is clicked :

```
     var input = $('#input').val();

       var data = {

        data : input
     };

     $.ajax({

        type: 'POST',
        url: 'index.php',
        data: data,
        dataType: 'text',
        succes: function(response){alert(response);},
        error: function(){alert("something went wrong");}  });
 });
```

});

my index.php is just :  echo 'apple'; , but it doesen't to anything when I click the button.

Answer (score 5):

You are missing s in success.

```
success: function(response){alert(response);},
```

Comment: that fixed it, but it returns source code of php file, how can I make it return  value that is being echoed?

Comment: A PHP script starts with <?php and ends with ?>. Have you added that?

Comment: yes, it just returns php src code, I've tried echoing json_encode('apple'); .. same thing

Comment: Are you running your application on any server or is it just running your html file in browser?

Comment: its running xamp on localhost

Comment: Actually, I am not a php person, just trying to debug your issue in the best possible way I can. Can you please try with data type as "json".

Comment: Well, i can only manage to address your actual issue of script. With respect to PHP not working as desired, either update the question with adding additional heading of update or post a separate question.

Comment: funny thing, it works in sublime text 3, but not in eclipse apatana. Thanks for your help !